# How to fix C++ header file location error for OpenCV on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, terminal, homebrew

I just finished the OpenCV installation on Mac OS X, but I'm continuously getting errors about my header files.  For example, when I add `#include <opencv2/core.hpp>` I immediately get back "'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found".
I started modifying the script to include the relative path instead, `#include "/Users/daniellebarnas/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp"` which removes the first error, but starts sending me down a rabbit hole of modifying every #include"HEADER FILE" within any relevant header files, 
e.g.

/Users/daniellebarnas/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/neon_utils.hpp:45:10: 'opencv2/core/cvdef.h' **file not found**

/Users/daniellebarnas/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:10: **In file included from** /Users/daniellebarnas/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:

/Users/daniellebarnas/Desktop/Mote/C++/OpenCV Tracker/OpenCV Tracker/main.cpp:11:10: **In file included from** /Users/daniellebarnas/Desktop/Mote/C++/OpenCV Tracker/OpenCV Tracker/main.cpp:11:

So I have to then go into each subsequent file and change the paths.
How can I build the code just using the standard #include or #include"HEADER FILE" without changing the path statements in every .hpp?
I installed OpenCV through Homebrew in Terminal, and I'm wondering if maybe there was an error in the installation or if there's something I can modify after the fact to fix this...

Comment: You have to tell the compiler to look in the directory "/Users/daniellebarnas/opencv-master/modules/core/include" for header files. I don't know how to do that on Mac, but there must be a setting 'include paths' in your IDE. For direct compiler calls, the syntax normally is `-I<dir>`

Comment: You need to config your header search path of your project. If you installed OpenCV with Homebrew, the "correct" location for headers is `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.x.x/include`. There, you would find a subdir `opencv2`, hence it makes `#include "opencv2/core.hpp" work. Another option would be to soft link that `opencv2` directory to standard header path `/usr/local/include`.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? Tags imply Homebrew, but in after reading question it seems to me that you have manually built it.

Comment: Have you tried to make symbolic link to directory "opencv2"?